# Highly upvoted question selected for audit gets closed. Selecting close for audit results in failure

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/27497353) in the Close Votes Review Queue. But I don't know how or ***why***!

As I nearly always do before taking any action other than "Skip," I opened the link in a separate tab (outside the queue). This showed that the question was ***already closed*** - which indicated to me (correctly) that it was an audit, and that the correct action was to "Vote to Close" (or so I assumed).

I did just this but, after voting to close (I gave "Needs Focus" as the reason, as that already showed with 2 votes) ... Bang! "Stop! Look! Listen! ..."

Is this a new, subtle, feature of the review audits system? Is it a bug? Or is there something else I missed?

Comment: IMO it's both: needs focus (as there are 2 questions) and seeking recommendation. If you close it as one of those you should pass the audit.. As you didn't, it is probably a bad audit

Comment: @Vickel Once I 'know' a review is an audit, I'm not really that concerned about what reason I give for a close vote ... it shouldn't matter. I've just noticed that the question has one reopen vote (not sure when that happened), so maybe that confused the system?

Comment: But it's not just a *bad* audit ... there's something *fundamentally wrong* with the system selecting a closed question as a "don't close" audit, IMHO.

Comment: That's indeed very strange, 'looks OK' or 're-open' passes the audit

Comment: The plot thickens with this [reopen](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/27606739) result. So it's both used as an audit to "Open", "Leave Open" and "Looks OK"  and it has a leave closed as an actual result.. ?!?

Comment: @Vickel I was going to ask if anyone would check that - interesting.

Comment: you can see that in the timeline

Comment: I just found your audit on the timeline too. It was enqueued on "Oct 29 at 1:33". And again at "Nov 6 at 16:31", you got the first one, which I find odd too. But basically the post was Open at the time it was enqueued. So maybe that's what trips up the system. The post wasn't actually closed until Nov.12th 15:30

Comment: It seems that the system isn't taking into account the close votes to invalidate audits.

Comment: The strange thing is, that only Adrian's audit shows `"Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully"`, all other do not show that message

Comment: Fun fact: The post was closed in about a minute from when it was posted in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/90230?m=50915158#50915158) on Nov. 12th at 15:29. I assume that's when the first close vote came in. The 15 minutes delay to the close vote queue is why one cannot see an entry on the timeline for that queue.

Comment: this is absolutely a bug: [faq at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/165773) says known good CV audits must have "no close votes" implying that _closed_ questions most definitely aren't qualified (as these have enough votes to close!). Consider retagging respectively. [meta-tag:status-review] would be desirable as well, but it can be set only by a moderator

Comment: @gnat I'm not so hot with use of tags on Meta, but please feel free to edit as you think best. (Braiam already made one tag change, which looks good, to me.)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370885/closing-a-question-should-perform-a-check-to-remove-it-from-known-good-audits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I just posted in a [similar bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370885/closing-a-question-thats-being-used-as-a-known-good-audit-should-immediately-re/371780#371780): I dug into this and implemented a fix that I think should resolve the issue. Basically I added in a check when a question is closed: is this question a current audit and is it a "known good post"? If so, invalidate it. That way, any status change like that will remove that type of potentially ambiguous audit from being used. It should be live today or tomorrow, so just let us know if you see any issues like this from next week on.

Comment: Not *quite* the same issue but a slightly less 'severe' case. [This known good audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/34042640) uses a post that has one pending close vote. The FAQ linked in the comment by gnat on this question says that should not happen.

Comment: Well, technically, it was selected as a known-good, close-vote audit prior to there being a close-vote cast on the question. However, when it was initially presented as an audit, it was skipped. The close-vote was placed after the initial audit was skipped. This audit was then presented to you several hours later, but it's the first CV queue audit that wasn't skipped since it was initially skipped. I can't easily tell if any of the "skip" responses between the initial "skip" were on other audits, but it's entirely possible that the presentation to you was the next audit in the entire CV queue.