# Failed a review audit by voting to close a question that is already closed

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed [this close votes audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/30081145) by voting to close it for lacking details or clarity. However, the post is already closed as lacking details or clarity and I don't believe I should fail an audit for choosing to do what the community has already decided on.

The question:

> **Google recaptcha v3- getting console error net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE 200 [closed]**
>
> Google recaptcha v3- working properly on my website, But I'm getting console error **net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE 200** How can I resolve this error ?
>
> Thanks

[This related meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322106/8289918) for a similar failed audit scenario says that the audit was just a bad audit that was eligible due to the number of upvotes. I suspect this is the case for this question: the question had 7 upvotes (before I downvoted it).

Comment: It looks like a known good one: A lot of upvotes.

Comment: The question was closed 2 hours ago. Perhaps it hasn't been booted from the audit pool yet. https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Related: [How (why) did I fail this close vote audit? Question closed 2 days ago used as "known good."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402877/how-why-did-i-fail-this-close-vote-audit-question-closed-2-days-ago-used-as)

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate because the other one is already marked for dev follow-up. If you ever get review suspended due to something like this, feel free to mod flag or post on Meta and we'll set it straight.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370885/closing-a-question-should-perform-a-check-to-remove-it-from-known-good-audits